# How do we know the Sacrament of Communion as practiced in the Catholic Church was instituted at the Last Supper?

Tags: catholicism, communion, passover

Communion is a common practice in the Roman Catholic Church. The tradition has a long history. Jesus kept the Passover since He followed the law. But there are Jewish traditions during Passover where you drink four cups of wine, break the bread, cover the bread, and hide it. How do we know Jesus did not do that and that He is not teaching us to celebrate Passover, to remember Him? He breaks the bread and dips it, gives blessings, signs hymns, and so on could well be a one part of a longer ritual the Jews where doing at the time and today.

Comment: Germia.Thank you for trying to improve my question.But My question here is more on the rituals.. that the RCC might be doing it wrong and where is the evidence for otherwise

Comment: Lack of research.  He's a place to start: [Scott Hahn, the Fourth Cup](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/56901/24204).  See also the Luke 17 and Luke 22.

Comment: As to "dipping the bread" that is a thing that the Greek Orthodox still do. (As I observed in an Orthodox liturgical celebration a couple of years ago).   Please do more basic research before asking a question. Also, look up the matter of "comingling" as it applies to Communion since you tagged this with catholicism.

Answer (score 3):

See [*How Christ Said the First Mass*](https://archive.org/details/howchristsaidfir00meag) by Fr. James L. Meagher, D.D.

Excerpt from its preface, [p. 11](https://archive.org/details/howchristsaidfir00meag/page/11):

> Worldly people look with wonder at the Mass, and Often say: What is the meaning of this form of divine worship? Where did these ceremonies come from? Why are candles lighted during daytime? Why do the priests wear such peculiar robes? Why don't they say the service in a language the people can understand?
>
> The Catholic sometimes says to himself: The Mass came from the Last Supper. But did Christ or the apostles say Mass as priest or bishop of our time? Did Christ that night follow any form of worship? If he did, where is it found? From ancient days the Church used the Ordinary of the Mass, but we do not know its origin.
>
> Many questions rise in people's minds to which they find no answer. A common opinion holds that Christ said the First Mass at the Last Supper according to a short form of blessing and prayer, then consecrated the bread and wine, gave the apostles Communion, and preached the sermon John's Gospel gives. When the apostles said Mass, they recited some Psalms, read the Scriptures, preached a sermon, consecrated the bread and wine, recited the Lord's Prayer and then gave Communion. In the apostolic age the saints added other prayers and ceremonies. Afterwards Popes and councils still more developed the rites, composed new prayers, and that during the Middle Ages the Mass grew and expanded into the elaborate Liturgy and Ceremonial of our day.
>
> But these opinions are wrong. From the beginning the Mass was said according to a long Liturgy and with ceremonies differing little from those of our time. No substantial addition was made after the apostolic age what the early Popes did was of minor importance—revisions and corrections. Little addition was made to the Ordinary of the Mass handed down from the days of Peter, founder of our Latin Liturgy.

Comment: So tradition is evidence?

Comment: @Levanger44, yes, in the Roman Catholic Church, tradition is a valid authority for doctrine, believing there is "_one common source ... with two distinct modes of transmission_".  On the other hand, most Protestant denominations claim to follow  [Sola Scriptura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_scriptura), the doctrine that the scriptures are the sole authority.